# Angular cli error after update

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I've updated the angular using the following commands: `npm update -g`, `npm upgrade -g`and now I got that error on using `ng serve`.

```
The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed.
Error: The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/lechucico/Documents/LegacyLife/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js:14:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/lechucico/Documents/LegacyLife/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/eject.js:10:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are in the right folder? I'm getting it when running it in a folder with an empty `node_modules` folder...

Comment: I'm on my project folder, so yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use with `-f` or `--force` flag it will work.

or go with this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5654)

Answer (score 0):

The first line says it all it's not properly install

Step 1.

npm uninstall -g angular-cli

Step 2.
npm cache clean

Step 3.
npm install -g angular-cli@latest

Then you can create new project with ng new myapp